# duplicate row formed in table when using PHP to store a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am making a site to display the family relations of an individual...I made use of PHP to store data from a form. I use access code to categorize different relations if an individual.  i.e..101-the relations of person X.
I need a bit of help as to why to an entry is being entered twice into the database.(new to PHP and first time asking for help here)
Thank you in Advance!
forms code(IN ct.php):

```
    <form id="frm1" action="ap.php" method="POST">
    access code: <input type="text" name="code_entered" value=""><br><br>
    position in family: <select name="fpos_entered">
        <option>Grandfather</option>
        <option>Grandmother</option>
        <option>Father</option>
        <option>Mother</option>
        <option>Brother</option>
        <option>Sister</option>
        <option>Uncle</option>
        <option>Aunt</option>
        <option>Nephew</option>
        <option>Niece</option>
        <option selected>Yourself</option>
    </select><br><br>
    name: <input type="text" name="name_entered" value=""><br><br>
    DOB:<input type="date" name="dob_entered" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i use the following PHP code to store the data from the form:

```
    <?php
include 'ct.php';
$temp="temp";
$conn= mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','','familytree');
if (!$conn)
{
die ('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}
if (isset($_POST['code_entered']))
{
    $acc= $_POST['code_entered'];
}if (isset($_POST['fpos_entered']))
{
    $fpos= $_POST['fpos_entered'];
}if (isset($_POST['name_entered']))
{
    $n= $_POST['name_entered'];
}if (isset($_POST['dob_entered']))
{
    $db= $_POST['dob_entered'];
}
$sql ="insert into temp values ('$acc', '$n','$fpos','$db')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<p>New record created successfully</p>.";
    }
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

which results in me having :
[pic of the database after 2 enteries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVudB.png)

Comment: You should use bind parameters instead of inserting directly the values from the _POST into the insert statement to the DB... otherwise, you'll have SQL injection, for sure.

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` inserts first record, `$conn->query($sql)` inserts __same__ second record. Understood?

Comment: Thank you for your Guidance. Thanks to all of you i see the errors in my program.

Comment: This is a typographical error. You queried twice as @u_mulder  pointed out.  Voting to close as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "familytree";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
INSERT INTO `temp` (code, fpos, name, dob) 
VALUES (:code, :fpos, :name, :dob)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':code', $_POST['code_entered'] ?? null);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fpos', $_POST['fpos_entered'] ?? null);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name_entered'] ?? null);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $_POST['dob_entered'] ?? null);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "<p>New record created successfully</p>.";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I recommend you to use PDO instead of mysqli. Also, bind the attributes coming from outside :)

Official docu: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: "I recommend you to use PDO instead of mysqli." - for what reason?

Comment: I personally find PDO easier than mysqli. I think is because PDO provides an api more likely as object-oriented. Anyway, both are working options nowadays. It is up to you which one. I found this comparison-link really interesting: https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-vs-mysqli

Comment: Another interesting link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-should-you-switch-pdo-from-mysql-mysqli-diwaker-mishra/

Comment: This IMHO does not answer the question; it's just a rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

you can change the code of this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<p>New record created successfully</p>.";
    }
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

into this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "<p>New record created successfully</p>.";
    }
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and also you must to be careful about sql injection so i think you must use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)